# How do I sort a Map inside a Map in Scala

Tags: scala

I have defined a `Map[Int, Map[String, Int]]`.

I know how to sort the outer Map, using ListMap. For example:

Actually all maps are mutable.

```
var myMap: Map[ Int, scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, Int] ] = Map()
....
// add some items to myMap
....
var sortedMap = scala.collection.immutable.ListMap( myMap.toList.sortBy{_._1}:_* )
```

But how do I sort the inner Map according to String?

The following seems to be wrong:

```
myMap foreach {
    case ( num, map ) ⇒ 
        map = scala.collection.immutable.ListMap( map.toList.sortBy{_._1}:_* ) 
}
```

Compiler says `map: reassignment to val`, but I already defined the inner map as `mutable.Map`. What can I do?

Comment: The compiler error is because the case statement in the partial function you are passing to `foreach` to extract the values from the tuple declares a `val num` and `val map`.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a function to each values using `mapValues` and then apply the same sorting function to the second map.

```
import scala.collection.immutable.ListMap

val myMap = Map[ Int, scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, Int] ] = Map()
....
// add some items to myMap
....
val outerSortedMap = ListMap(myMap.toList.sortBy{_._1}:_* )
val innerSortedMap = myMap.mapValues(innerMap => 
  ListMap(innerMap.toList.sortBy{_._1}:_* )
)
```

**Sorting both the inner and the outer Map**

For this, you just need to first sort the outer Map (so you get `outerSortedMap` as explained above), and then to sort the inner Maps of `outerSortedMap`.

```
val innerOuterSortedMap = outerSortedMap.mapValues(innerMap =>
  ListMap(innerMap.toList.sortBy{_._1}:_*)
)
```

**Concerning your attempt**

The foreach method has the following signature: `foreach[U](f: ((A, B)) ⇒ U): Unit`, so it is a side-effect method. What you want is to apply a function to all values of your `map` and to then replace the values by the result of the function. This is basically a `map` function (yes `map` represents two totally different things), and as you want to map values, then the function `mapValues` exists!

Comment: Yeah, I understand your approach. Thanks. By the way, is there any way to change myMap after sorting both outer map and inner map? You just give a result for a innerSortedMap, but I want a change on the myMap, so that both the outer and the inner are sorted.

Comment: @user1725406 please see my edit, basically you just need to sort the inner part of the `outerSortedMap`.

Comment: Hello, what if all the Maps are mutable, then your approach will fail. Do you know how to sort mutable Map? Thanks.

Comment: Just take the values, sort them, and put them back. But first, why would you want to sort a Map, as the goal is to access values by key?

Answer (score 0):

You could also consider using [`TreeMap`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.TreeMap). This way you won't need to sort the maps later.

Note that there is no mutable `TreeMap`, but this isn't a big issue (maybe it's even intentional). Having a mutable `TreeMap` doesn't bring a considerable benefit, as adding an element to an balanced tree takes *O(log n)*, no matter if we consider the structure mutable or immutable.

This also means that using `TreeMap` has the same asymptotic complexity as having some other kind of collection and sorting it later. Adding *n* elements to a `TreeMap` will take *n O(log n) = O(n log n)* , which is just the same as sorting a list of *n* elements.

Also note that the constructors of `TreeMap` have an implicit argument `ordering: Ordering[A]`. By setting it explicitly when creating the map, you can plug in your own sorting function, if you want to sort using some different criterion than the default.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty clean if you define a `sortMap` helper function for yourself:

```
def sortMap[K: Ordering, V](m: scala.collection.Map[K, V]) = 
  ListMap(m.toList.sortBy { _._1 }: _*)

val doubleSortedMap = sortMap(myMap.mapValues(sortMap(_)))
```